# How to view throughput using a SELECT?

Tags: sql-server-2012

This seems like it should be simple. I am trying to get an idea of the read transfer rate on a DB using a SELECT statement. e.g. I want 'x MB/sec'. The table to be used in this query has millions of rows.

I have tried using SET IO STATISTICS ON/OFF on either side of my SELECT but this doesn't return the transfer rate to me, I just get the number of rows affected and # of reads, writes.

Comment: You cannot get this information from SSMS.  However, asking your question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ may give you more results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way I can think of is to load up perfmon on your machine and watch it while you're doing the select. This will give you the transfer rate to your machine from the DB.

If you want to know the IO to disk on the DB, then you'll probably have to stop all other loads, load up perfmon on the DB, and watch it while you're executing the select. This result is highly dependent on how much of the data is already in the cache.

If you can't isolate your select, then you can average what your baseline is and see how much more throughput there is during your select.

If you can't pull up perfmon, then you can see if the relevant counters are in sys.dm_os_performance_counters (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187743.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. My searches suggested perfmon as well so looks like I'll be utilizing it.